# ubuntu install wubi?

Tags: windows, wubi

first, sorry about my poor english.
i have win 8.1 pre installed.
i have tried to install ubuntu on another disk, i make another and gave him 30GB .
then i download ubuntu 14 amd64 and Universal USB Installer.
i installed the ubuntu with the UUI on a flash drive(DOK).
*my secureboot is disable if its help*
i reboot my laptop, and nothing happend no image of ubuntu.
ok, i try to install from windows. i opened the dok floder and then i saw "WUBI".exe
i opened it and its ask me if i want to reboot my computer to install ubuntu, or i want to install it from the windows.
i chose the first option, its reboot and nothing happened.usually.
then i chose the second, and its start to install some "ubuntu" floder on my c disk.
so i stopped it cause i thought its a bad thing.
in this ubuntu floder i see ubuntu.exe and uninstaller-wubi.exe and more floders.
what to do?
i wanna install ubuntu with dual boot.
u have some advice?

Comment: Do not use wubi. It has not been updated to work with gpt partitioned drives that all new UEFI based systems have.  Review these: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-support

Comment: You need to get your boot options menu from BIOS (EFI) and tell it to boot from the USB: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C50dJf5MweM (That first option in Wubi, all it does is restart the computer... literally nothing else).

Answer (score 0):

Wubi runs like a windows program.  I've not had much experience with it, but I know that it does not need or make its own partition.  It simply installs into the c: (or wherever).

In my experience, the best way to install a dual boot is to boot up from the ubuntu USB, and then (if everything is working) install from there.  This will give you the option to select which partition to use for the Ubunut install.

Comment: thats the problem. i could not boot up the ubuntu from the usb.